# Windows 7 Setup can't detect my keyboard/mouse

Tags: windows-7

I just bought my new computer and i prefer win 7 over 10 so i tried installing win 7 and in the setup i can't use my keyboard or my mouse. I tried multiple ports, 2.0/3.0 and still doesn't work. What can I do ? 
Motherboard : Gigabyte B450M DS3H-CF
Keyboard : Redragon Vara
Mouse : Steelseries Rival 110
Processor : AMD Ryzen 5 1500x

Comment: B450 Chipsets & AMD Ryzen use xHCI controller for USB 2 & USB 3 ports for which Windows 7 does not have any native drivers. So USB ports will not function with Windows 7 installer. You need to slipstream USB 3 drivers into Windows 7 Installer for this to work.

Comment: the AMD USB 3.0 xHC Host Controller Driver ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer AMD Ryzen CPUs and AM4 Chipsets use xHCI controller for both USB 2.0 & USB 3.0 ports for which Windows 7 does not have any native drivers. As a result Windows 7 installer boots but no devices plugged into USB 2 or 3 ports are functional during installation.

In order to solve this you need to slipstream USB 3 drivers into the Windows 7 installer.

Gigabyte has provided an easy to use GUI utility called 'Windows USB Installation Tool' to do the same.

The utility can be downloaded from [here](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Utility/mb_utility_windowsimagetool_B18.0213.1.zip).

You would first need a working Windows computer to process this.

Download and unzip to a folder and run the file WindowsImageTool.exe preferably as admin.

Create a UEFI Bootable Windows 7 USB installer using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) and plug it into the working Windows computer and start the utility.

[image]

In the destination path, select the Windows 7 USB installer USB drive.
Check 'Add USB drivers' and proceed. All AMD xHCI drivers are already present in the utility. You need not download anything separately from the Internet.

This will slipstream the USB 3 drivers into each and every Index inside install.wim so the process may go on for 30 - 40 minutes.
Once the process ends, use the modified USB installer to install Windows 7 and hopefully this time you should not get this issue.

Set UEFI / BIOS to optimized defaults and in case there's any option for xHCI Handoff, enable the same in BIOS.

If you are installing Windows 7 on an NVMe drive, then you should also select 'Add NVMe drivers' and 'Add Packages' so that your NVMe drive should hopefully get detected by Windows 7.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try see if this works after it finishes installing.