# Installing Windows 7 on laptot with only USB 3 ports (standard solution does not work)

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

I am trying to install Windows 7 Pro on a 2015 Alienware 13" computer that previously had Windows 8.1. The standard procedure to do it with only USB 3 ports is to include USB 3 drivers in the installation medium as described e.g. [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/mini-pcs/nuc-kits/Install-Win7-to-USB3_0-Computers.pdf) or [here](http://woshub.com/adding-usb-3-0-controller-drivers-to-windows-7-install-media/). I followed the instructions and verified that the drivers are implemented in both the `boot.wim` and `install.wim` files, in `boot.wim` in both indices, in `install.wim` in the index for Windows professional version.

I use the Dell drivers called `Chipset_Driver_K2J3K_WN64_3.0.2.54_A01.EXE`. I tried Intel drivers that VmWare links for virtual machines but those could only be implemented in `boot.wim`, they would not be implemented in `install.wim`.

When I boot from the flash drive with "patched" `boot.wim` and `install.wim`, the external mouse does not work, after clicking on install, i get the typical dialogue "A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. ..."

I assume at this stage, the system is looking for drivers in the `boot.wim` file?

Since the mouse does not work, i assume that it would not help if i had a usb 2 flash drive?

Can someone provide an advice how to proceed?

Comment: You have verified the USB 3 chipset your device uses is compatible with the driver you are attempting to use?

Comment: Try Gigabyte's Windows Install Utility. It has large collection of most common USB 3 xHCI drivers for both Intel & AMD Systems. See if this answer helps. https://superuser.com/questions/1549499/windows-7-setup-cant-detect-my-keyboard-mouse/1549512#1549512

Comment: @Ramhound Well the drivers are from Dell's support site for the service tag of the computer and for Windows 7 x64.

Comment: exe drivers wont work, you need a compatible driver for use with integration. Intel use to have a utility to inject their usb3.0 drivers into a windows 7 image but it has been taken down>>>https://web.archive.org/web/20160610233808/https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility

Comment: I \have a copy if you want it. Let me know

Comment: Or use the more reliable gigabyte tool found on this page>>>https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/intelusb3creatorutilityv3/